# JQuery slideDown() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cant get the greenbar to slidedown when the page loads. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Live Green Plants
</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
<script src="home.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="headerBar">
<img src="headerBar.png" width="657" height="34" alt=""/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery-ui-1.8.18.min.js"></script>




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.headerBar').slideDown('slow');
});
```

Comment: you have included your script which used jQuery before jQuery is included... so place your `<script src="home.js"></script>` after `<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery-ui-1.8.18.min.js"></script>`

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/D6wn6/ : and this is how it will work, so hide it before you slideDown it possibly `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/D6wn6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to start off as invisible, using `style="display:none"`
See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jas6H/5/

Comment: What's strange is it works in jfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jas6H/8/ but my index.html file is a white page with no green bar at all?

Comment: @user3661876, perhaps you tried to use jquery before it was imported as others have suggested here. just move your script tag after jquery's script tag

Comment: I updated my code http://jsfiddle.net/jas6H/8/ and the screen is still blank even after putting the .js file after jquery link.

Comment: @user3661876, did you use `$(document).ready`, it's possible the div does not exist at the time `$('.headerBar').slideDown('slow');` was called.

Comment: I added $(document).readyand updated the jsfiddle and changed it to fadeIn() instead, but it wont fadeIn from my index.html file, but it works in jsfiddle

Comment: @user3661876, can you post the content of all pertinent html and js files in your post?

Comment: try this one, http://jsfiddle.net/jas6H/12/, where all script tags have been moved after the div